# Dynamic scrolling of NestedScrollView based on the content of TabBarView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've got a screen having some content on top of a `TabBar`.

[image]

Both the content above `TabBar` and in `TabBarView` can be of dynamic height.
My use case is that the upper content should only be scrollable when all of the content is not visible and only up to the point that all of it becomes visible and not beyond that. So in the following example, only `Tab 1` should be scrollable.

[dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=20e593bee1ce6b729f38cda71bcb9e9f&null_safety=true)

Setting the scrollphysics to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` wouldn't work since I can't determine the scroll behavior beforehand because of the dynamic height of the contents. [Using `SliverAppBar`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94332#issuecomment-990477475) also doesn't work for the same reason.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final length = 5;

  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> _tabs = <String>['Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3'];
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: _tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle:
                    NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            const Text('Upper Content'),
                            ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, __) => Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: const Text('Items'),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: TabBar(
                          tabs: _tabs
                              .map(
                                (String name) => Tab(
                                  text: name,
                                ),
                              )
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: _tabs.map((String name) {
              return name.split(' ')[1] != '3'
                  ? SafeArea(
                      top: false,
                      bottom: false,
                      child: Builder(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return CustomScrollView(
                            key: PageStorageKey<String>(name),
                            slivers: <Widget>[
                              SliverOverlapInjector(
                                handle: NestedScrollView
                                    .sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                              ),
                              SliverPadding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
                                  itemExtent: 48.0,
                                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      return ListTile(
                                        title: Text('Item $index'),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    childCount:
                                        name.split(' ')[1] != '2' ? 15 : 5,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dartpad link not opening, basically you want that active tab should be scrollable after loading data and before loading the data tabbar should be scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

`TabBarView` requires finite height while wrapping with scrollable widget and on others cases all tabs become scrollable. Also trying with `IndexedStack` provide the same behavior.

> I am not using `TabBarView`.

I am loading widgets for tabs inside `initState` and just passing inside body.

Run on [dartPad.](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c961ac49049c7aae6d6e2c39dfd8aa27&null_safety=true)

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final length = 8;

  late final TabController controller;
  final List<String> _tabs = <String>['Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3'];

  List<Widget> tabViews = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TabController(
      length: _tabs.length,
      vsync: this,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    tabViews = List.generate(
        _tabs.length,
        (index) => Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                ...List.generate(
                  index * 3 + 2,
                  (itb) => Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: 100,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff)),
                    child: Text("Tab: $index item  $itb"),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                ...List.generate(
                  5,
                  (index) => Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text(" top item $index"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.primaries.first,
              height: kToolbarHeight,
              child: TabBar(
                tabs: _tabs.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ),
            tabViews[controller.index],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That would definitely not be performing. There will probably be more than one Text in each and Column will build everything in it at once. Also in each setState. I need some time for a better suggestion

Comment: Widget tree is smart enough on update cases, and we can replace  `SingleChildScrollView` with `CustomScrollView` and for inner column widgets, we can separate the context for heavy widgets. Feel free to add your answer